# How do I convert PWSTR to string in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I have the following code:

```
// Fetch Local App Data folder path.
PWSTR localAppData = (PWSTR) malloc(128);
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &localAppData);

// Find out the absolute path to chrome.exe
stringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << "/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe";
```

The result of stringstreamer's `.str()` is `008F6788/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe`, which is wrong.

I can't seem to get stringstreamer to work, neither do strcat or wcsncat due to type incompatibilities.

How do I cast this PWSTR to string?

Comment: See my answer for one way to convert between multibyte and wide char and vice versa. See Andre's for another way. See Praetorian or Tomalak Geret'kal for what you should do.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## 1. Yuk!

Microsoft [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230355%28v=prot.10%29.aspx):

```
typedef wchar_t* LPWSTR, *PWSTR;
```

So let's get that horrid nonsense out of your testcase, and lose the C rubbish:

```
// Fetch Local App Data folder path.
wchar_t* localAppData = new wchar_t[128];
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &localAppData);

stringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << "/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe";

delete[] localAppData;
```

---

## 2. Warning!

**There is a serious flaw here.**

`SHGetKnownFolderPath` actually sets the value of the pointer you give it to point to memory that *it* allocated. Your code has a memory leak, and my last snippet frees the memory subtly wrongly.

Let's fix that by reading [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> *ppszPath* [out]
>
> ```
> Type: PWSTR*
> ```
>
> When this method returns, contains the address of a pointer to a null-terminated Unicode string that specifies the path of the known folder. The calling process is responsible for freeing this resource once it is no longer needed by calling CoTaskMemFree. The returned path does not include a trailing backslash. For example, "C:\Users" is returned rather than "C:\Users\".

```
// Fetch Local App Data folder path.
wchar_t* localAppData = 0;
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &localAppData);

stringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << "/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe";

CoTaskMemFree(static_cast<void*>(localAppData));
```

Now, on with the show.

---

## 3. Wide characters

The syntax issue with your code is that localAppData is a `wchar_t`, but normal `stringstream`s work on `char`.

Fortunately, there is a wide-char variant called `wstringstream` that uses `wchar_t` instead.

(Note that this means your literal will have to be built out of `wchar_t`s, too, using the `L` string literal prefix.)

And now the final code:

```
// Fetch Local App Data folder path.
wchar_t* localAppData = 0;
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &localAppData);

wstringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << L"/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe";

CoTaskMemFree(static_cast<void*>(localAppData));
```

Comment: +1 but would not a `wchar_t` array be a bit better than a vector? Also `MAX_PATH` might be worth mentioning. Nevermind, nice edit and good eyes on `CoTaskFreeMem`

Comment: @AJG85: No vectors in my answer. `SHGetKnownFolderPath` does the allocation for you.

Comment: How do I now convert wstringstream into string? Actually, I am interested in c_str because I use the result for `stat` and I can get c_str from string.

Comment: @rFactor: `ss.str()` gives you a `std::wstring`. You see the pattern here? :) For further questions, consult the documentation for `std::wstringstream` in your favourite C++ Standard Library reference.

Comment: @rFactor: And you're about to run into problems because you have a wide string, but want to use it with `stat` which does _not_ want a wide string. But that's a whole separate question.

Comment: @Tomalak Your code has a problem too :-) `CoTaskMemFree` takes a void pointer, not a pointer to a void pointer.

Comment: Who knew something that sounds as simple as querying the OS for a path would turn into such a minefield!

Comment: @Praetorian: I say again: "Yuk! Microsoft" ;-)

Answer (score 5):

`PWSTR` is a pointer to a wide-character string. You need

```
// Fetch Local App Data folder path.
PWSTR localAppData = (PWSTR) malloc(128);
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &localAppData);

wstringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << L"/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe";
```

Also, `malloc` argument indicates the number of bytes to allocate, so you're allocating a buffer that can only hold 64 wide characters (including the NULL character). You might want to use `malloc( 128 * sizeof(wchar_t) )`.

**EDIT:**
From the documentation for [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

> *ppszPath* When this method returns, contains the address of a pointer to a null-terminated Unicode string that specifies the path of the known folder. The calling process is responsible for freeing this resource once it is no longer needed by calling `CoTaskMemFree`

So you shouldn't be allocating any memory for the last argument for the function.

```
wchar_t *localAppData = NULL;
::SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &localAppData);

wstringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << L"/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe";
::CoTaskMemFree(localAppData);
```

Comment: This would also fail.  You need to prefix the string litteral with `L`, as in `L"..."`.

Comment: Don't you need a wide string literal there?

Comment: @André Caron Oops, that's what I get for not trying it out first! Fixed.

Comment: How do I now convert wstringstream into string? Actually, I am interested in c_str because I use it for `stat`.

Comment: This won't work. `SHGetKnownFolderPath` allocates memory and changes `localAppData` to point to it, which is going to be a problem if it's an array. :)

Comment: You should still at least _initialise_ the pointer. It's UB to "use" it otherwise; at least with a null pointer it's merely UB to _dereference_ it.

Comment: Out of curiosity and because this is hard to google: What's the point on the trailing "::" before your api function calls?

Comment: @Gaspa79 It's indicating the *global namespace* (you can Google that). By using `::` before those function names I'm using qualified name lookup and there's no ambiguity which functions are intended to be called.

Comment: @Praetorian Ohhh right, usings will not affect that and you avoid naming collisions that way. Smart. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I like <strike>Praetorina's</strike>Praetorian's answer of just using wide string stream but if you want to convert:

```
char str[128];
wcstombs(str, localAppData, 128);
```

There is another function which goes the other way around too:

```
wchar_t wstr[128];
mbstowcs(wstr, "Hello World", 128);
```

Comment: Freudian slip? Amazing what two letters swapped can do ;-P

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "cast" a wide-character string to a string.  The reason (other than the 2-byte unit VS. 1-byte unit issue) is that this "cast" would be ambiguous.

What is the source encoding?  What is the destination encoding?  In this case, the source encoding is likely to be Unicode (shell extensions may return random crap, nothing guarantees that they performed a valid X-to-Unicode conversion if they weren't using Unicode).  The destination encoding is likely to be ASCII, although it technically has to match the system's current codepage.

If you want a lossy Unicode-to-ASCII conversion, you can use [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Most of the other answers aren't relevant to what people googling this topic would want...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like widechar and want ansi string badly, try wcstombs or WideCharToMultiByte.

To call SHGetKnownFolderPath, you don't need to allocate memory by yourself, it will cause memory leak.