# C++ createprocess of file in program files

Tags: c++, windows, windows-shell

I'm trying to use `CreateProcess` in order to run a file that is located on the user's Program Files directory, so I'm trying to use `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86` since that specific program will always be on the (x86) folder.

My problem is that I can't get it to work, for some reason I cannot find any example of how to use `createprocess` and `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86`

Can you direct me to such example? Maybe I should use a different function?

**EDIT**:

This is my current code:

```
wchar_t* localAppData = 0;
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86, 0, NULL, &localAppData);

wstringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << L"/MyApp/MyExe.exe";

CreateProcess(static_cast<void*>(localAppData));
```

I'm getting this for teh `SHGetFolderPath`:

`cannot convert parameter 5 from wchar_t ** to LPWSTR`

Also, even though I've included sstream in the headers, I'm getting these errors:

`'wstringstream' : undeclared identifier`

Note: I'm using SHGetFolderPath as I need this to work on both XP and Vista/7

Any ideas?

Comment: C++ isn't that complicated. #include <sstream> and use std::wstringstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the C style string handling that you need for the Windows API:

```
wchar_t localAppData[MAX_PATH]; // Array, not a pointer.
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES, 0, NULL, localAppData);

std::wstringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << L"/MyApp/MyExe.exe";

CreateProcess(ss.str().c_str(), ...);
```

Also, note that only `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES` is supported with `SHGetFolderPath`.

Comment: This works, thanks! Is there any way of using CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES or any other variable that will allow this code to run on all Win XP/7/Vista?

Comment: `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES`, while deprecated, still works on all Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in winapi docs, perhaps it will help.

Edit:

Seems that one is deprecated, so use [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Edited according to comment:

Use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you are on vista and above.

Edit: [Example stackoverflow code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448057/how-do-i-convert-pwstr-to-string-in-c)

You can just replace the CoTaskMemFree with CreateProcess.

Comment: deprecated as well. It seems that the function to use is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @steffen it isn't deprecated, your function doesn't exist on xp.

Comment: deprecated as well. It seems that the function to use is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry for the double post. XP wasn't mentioned. That said, you're right, pwned.

Comment: Sorry for the double post. XP wasn't mentioned. That said, you're right, pwned.

Comment: Can you guys maybe show me a quick example of how to use it in conjunction of createprocess?

Comment: @user838437: Just call any of the `SH*` functions to retrieve the path (use a `WCHAR[MAX_PATH]` string buffer); append your exe name, and pass that string to `CreateProcess`.