# How to convert PWSTR to QString to display in a listbox

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm  trying to get text displayed in a listbox on Qt. I know that a listbox on Qt only accepts QString, so I've tried using the example here: [How do I convert PWSTR to string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448057/how-do-i-convert-pwstr-to-string-in-c) and converted it to a wstring before converting to to a QString.
Doing this, I get something similar to this in the listbox:

��������������������ፉ靏Ṯ耀������������������������������������������Ý

If I print it out on the console it gives me what I want. How can I get it to display correctly in the listbox. 
How can I get it to display in the listbox correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use QString's [`fromWCharArray`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromWCharArray) static function:

```
wchar_t* my_string = ...;
QString qstring = QString::fromWCharArray(my_string);
```

Note that if `my_string` is not null-terminated, `fromWCharArray()` has an overload that takes a 2nd parameter for the string length:

```
wchar_t* my_string = ...;
size_t my_len = ...;
QString qstring = QString::fromWCharArray(my_string, my_len);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `wstring` for the variable name, to avoid confusion with `std::wstring`

Comment: @RemyLebeau fair enough, updated the answer to reflect your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Steve Lorimers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47439839/7478597), here mine with [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <shlobj.h>

int main()
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version: " << QT_VERSION_STR;

  wchar_t *localAppData = nullptr;
  SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &localAppData);

  QString qStr = QString::fromWCharArray(localAppData);
  CoTaskMemFree(static_cast<void*>(localAppData));

  qDebug() << "localAppData (as QString):" << qStr;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested with VS2013:

```
Qt Version:  5.9.2
localAppData (as QString): "C:\\Users\\Scheff\\AppData\\Local"
```

The resp. function is [`QString::fromWCharArray()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromWCharArray).