# Robust ways to get App Data Folder Path for Non English Window User

Tags: c++, file, window

I was using this code well to get the App Data Folder path for my C++ application.

```
    char* actFilePath = NULL;
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];


    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath)))
    {
        PathAppend(szPath, _T("\\MyFile.txt"));
        actFilePath = wchar_to_string(szPath);
    }
```

When I run the this code over some of Non English Window 8 or Window 10 OS, this code fails (actFilePath is just null). I found that the code fails due the non English User name in the folder path like débarquer Matyáš or 姓 名 as you can see from the path below:

```
C:\Users\débarquer Matyáš\AppData\Local
C:\Users\姓 名\AppData\Local
```

What are more robust approach and less prone to error just in case some user name is written in their native language even including Chinese or Japanese or European, etc. Working code example will be really appreciated.

Kind regards.

=====================================================================

Updated to the answer from VTT on 12 Nov 2018

I created this code following the answer from VTT.
This code compiles fine. However, the returned folder path is behaving unexpected. Sometimes, it gives me the correct path but sometimes, it returns unreadable file path. Something like this. See attached link for some strange characters. Some impression I am getting is this code is unstable.

https://ibb.co/goLzxq

```
    wchar_t* actFilePath = NULL;

    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &actFilePath)))
    {
        PathAppendW(actFilePath, L"\\MyFile.txt");
    }
```

I have followed some advice from this answer too here.

[How do I convert PWSTR to string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448057/how-do-i-convert-pwstr-to-string-in-c)

Comment: switching your project to a unicode build will probably fix it, alternatively just avoid the whole `TCHAR` mess, use `wchar_t` instead and call `SHGetFolderPathW` explicitly.

Comment: I checked my compiler and in fact it did compiled with Unicode setting. So your first suggestion does not work. I guess it is sensitive to window OS.

Answer (score 1):

`SHGetFolderPath` is deprecated. You should use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` instead. Note that this new function only has wide char version so it works with Unicode paths properly.

```
PWSTR psz_path{};
auto const hr
{
    ::SHGetKnownFolderPath
    (
        FOLDERID_LocalAppData
    ,   KF_FLAG_DEFAULT
    ,   HANDLE{}
    ,   ::std::addressof(psz_path)
    )
};
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    assert(psz_path);
    // do something with path...
    ::CoTaskMemFree(psz_path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. As I have updated. The code I have created is behaving strange giving me some path contained Unicode,etc. Can you suggest how to append the app data folder path with file name for further use with wchar_t* filename.

Comment: @auto9817 Pointer value returned by this function will point to the buffer large enough to hold only the folder path, so by appending something to it with `PathAppendW` you will get a buffer overrun and memory corruption. You should allocate separate buffer large enough to hold full file path and then append folder path and file name to that buffer. Actually just use `::std::wstring`. And you should not convert it path to `char` or `::std::string`.

Comment: Thanks. You are very kind.