# Where are the golang environment variables stored?

Tags: go

I am just started learning golang on Windows 7.

With `go env`, I got this:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=E:\Workbench\Go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\DevTools\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\DevTools\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
```

Then I checked with `echo %envVar%` in the command line, I found env vars like:

```
GOPATH
GOROOT
```

But others are not found.

So where are they stored? Some hidden configuration file?

Comment: Read `go help env` and `go help environment`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are just the defaults for your platform.  Think of them as stored in the go.exe executable itself.

You can override them by setting them to something else like any other env var.

Comment: But for the `GOTOOLDIR`, if it is in the go.exe, how can it know the installation location of go on my box? Or it infers it from the `GOROOT`?

Comment: And the `set` part gives me an impression that it is adding those variables to my environment.

Comment: I assume the go tool is calling the win32 api to get it's own location then computing a default path from there.  See example of that api here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647429/c-windows-path-to-the-folder-where-the-executable-is-located

Comment: as for the "set", `go env` prints the environment as is appropriate to set it on the host platform.  ie: on a mac (via homebrew), it prints `GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.3/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"`

Answer (score 20):

In go1.13, customized GOENVs are stored in GOENV, which is specified by system environment variable. If not specified, the default value for your platform will be used.

To obtain default location for your platform, use `go env GOENV`: on Linux you'll get `$HOME/.config/go/env`, and on macOS you'll get `$HOME/Library/Application Support/go/env`.

```
$ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/leonardo/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/home/leonardo/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/leonardo/.config/go/env" # if system environment 'GOENV' is empty, the default value for your platform will be used.
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/leonardo/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn,direct" # default value is "https://proxy.golang.org,direc"
```

```
$ cat ~/.config/go/env
GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn,direct
```

environment variables defined with form "KEY=VALUE" in this file will override the default value hard coded at https://github.com/golang/go/blob/57662b1575030aa09043cd7a48425abdc6e0e0a3/src/cmd/go/internal/cfg/cfg.go#L229

Comment: On Windows the default `GOENV` seems to point to `%APPDATA%\go\env`.

Answer (score 8):

Please type the following command to your command prompt

```
> go env GOENV
/root/.config/go/env
```

Answer (score 6):

Like what @David Budworth says, those variables are the defaults for your platform.

Most of case we change `$GOPATH` and `$GOROOT` variables. For example in my PC i use `export GOPATH=/home/user/go` and yours may be different from mine.

Otherwise, if you look to find where other variables are stored you need to look at `/usr/lib/go-1.6/src` (sorry i'm using `Ubuntu` right now with go 1.6 and i don't know the path directory of go in Windows), you'll find there many `bash` [scripts](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src) used when you built your `go executable`.

For example:

in the file: [make.bash](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/make.bash#L166) you'll see: `$GROOT` was declared there and used to build the final `go executable`:

```
export GOROOT="$(cd .. && pwd)"
```

I saw, also, your comments about `GOTOOLDIR` and how it knows your installation location of go in your box. I would say, that the source code of go have the answer and you can find it [here](https://git.ustclug.org/zhsso/go/blob/0ab3ea9738bb28211c156faf38923bb6c28952cb/src/pkg/go/build/path.go):

```
// ToolDir is the directory containing build tools.
var ToolDir = filepath.Join(runtime.GOROOT(), "pkg/tool/"+runtime.GOOS+"_"+runtime.GOARCH)
```

**Edit:**
I found this good article about building go: [How GO uses to build itself](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/04/how-go-uses-go-to-build-itself)

**PS:** Sorry for my english. I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't literally do: `export GOPATH=/home/user/go/src`, but instead do: `export GOPATH=/home/user/go`, otherwise you'd have $HOME/go/src/src/STUFF YOU GO GET

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake and you're right. The correct path is `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` or `export GOPATH=/user_path/go`. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

by default, `env_file` does not exist on mac_os.

```
env_file: $HOME/Library/Application Support/go/env
```

after doing "`go env -w $HOME/go`", the `env_file` was created.

Comment: Mine existed by default.